# Show ReleaseName in DevOps WorkItem

Tags: azure-devops, devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is there a way to show the ReleaseName of a release pipeline somewhere in the workitem view?
I can see the deployment in the upper right corner, but I can see only the "static" names configured in the pipeline. I want to show the actual version for that specific release.

[image: Deployment]

When I go to "links" I see the list of runs with the changed release name (latest 20230728.4)

[image]

I would like to see the latest release directly in the WorkItem. Is this possible?